# Every single logo, advert, presentation and video IS or ARE?

Tags: grammaticality

I know that every single is followed by singular, but what if there are different units after "every single"?

Comment: IS, for sure. Why are you using all caps?

Comment: *Every* is singular, *single* is singular. *Logo* is singular. You don't say "Every single person are", do you now.

Comment: It's a deleted form of 'Every single logo is .... , every single advert is ...., every single presentation is .... and every single video is [available on Me-Tunnel]'.

Comment: The process is called "[Conjunction Reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20conjunction%20reduction)" and extends the scope of the quantifier _every_ to the following parallel constructions, so it doesn't have to be repeated, except for optional emphasis.